# Binding XML attribute in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, binding

I have this variable in Model class:

```
[Bindable]
public var someXml:XML;
```

I've used BindingUtils to get notified when the XML changes:

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(onChange, Model.getInstance(), "someXml");

private function onChange(value:Object):void {
    // do something
}
```

Function `onChange` gets triggered when I assign an XML to the variable, but not when I change some attribute of the XML:

```
Model.getInstance().someXml.@attr = "newValue";
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because XML isn't an EventDispatcher and so doesn't dispatch Change Events when it's contents change. It descends directly from Object, so there's no EventDispatcher.

Comment: do you know a way to bind XML attributes?

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way of doing it. My suggestion would be to encapsulate the change you want to make to the xml in a method on the model, so you can dispatch the change event from the model and get the binding to fire that way. Model.getInstance().updateXML( attrName, newValue );

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [XMLNotifier class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/XMLNotifier.html)

*"... Used for watching changes to XML and XMLList objects. Those objects are not EventDispatchers, so if multiple elements want to watch for changes they need to go through this mechanism. Call watchXML(), passing in the same notification function that you would pass to XML.notification. Use unwatchXML() to remove that notification."*

Those are the only two functions of interest and I think they are self explanatory.